# Debian package's files authentication

Tags: debian, authentication, hashsum

I know that `dpkg` keeps md5sums of configuration files for each package installed, so it can tell whether they are changed or not when upgrading.

Does it keep md5sums for regular (non-configuration) files as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, look at the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums`. Strictly speaking this isn't handled by `dpkg`; these checksums are generated at build-time (typically by `dh_md5sums`) and included in the binary packages.

You can check that the installed files still match their MD5 checksums using the `debsums` command.